# 7001 TypeError: zmq.Context is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, zeromq, tsconfig

So I am running

```
tsc --build tsconfig.json
```

with the tsconfig file at the bottom of this post. Then I package the code -

```
pkg .\dist\server.js --output MyAppExe --targets node16-win-x64 --debug --public -
```

When I run the MyAppExe, I see this error:

```
Failed to send request to zmqLayer TypeError: zmq.Context is not a constructor
    at defaultContext (C:\snapshot\backend\node_modules\zeromq\lib\index.js:183:9)
    at new <anonymous> (C:\snapshot\backend\node_modules\zeromq\lib\index.js:299:37)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\backend\node_modules\zeromq\lib\index.js:751:14)
```

I have also see a couple other TS errors like *"TypeError: zmq.zmqVersion is not a function"* - but I am not sure why. In the config below I should have the ts set to ignore both js and node_module files. And zeromq is all JS.

And pkg turns js into an exe...so I am not sure where this is going wrong.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "checkJs": false
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "lib": ["esnext"],
  "paths": [
    "global.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": ["./src", "./server.ts"],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
    "./node_modules",
    "./node_modules/*",
    "./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts",]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I found out the solution below still didn't solve all the issues. Still got the line above. I resolved this and the other typescript error by manually editing the files. Seems to have worked, but there should be a better way to do this.

pkg wasn't finding the prebuilt binaries for some reason. It was looking for

```
node.abi88.node.win.v16.16.0
```

when the files are named

```
node.abi88.node
```

Found this out when I placed a console.log in pgk, producer.js line 118

```
console.log(nativeFile);
```

When I changed the name of the file some of the issues went away. Now only two TS ones remain...